# AppCompat Theme make EditText cursor to left

Tags: android, android-edittext, cursor, themes

I am using a style in the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

When I use the normal style `android:Theme.Black.NoTitleBar`

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="right"
     android:hint="hint content"/>
```

the `EditText` cursor is at the right of the "hint content"[image]

But if I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, the `EditText` cursor is always at the left of the "hint content".

How can I have the cursor at the right of the "hint content" when I use
`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`?